# How to track Django model changes with git?

Tags: python, sql, django, git, workflow

Suppose you write a Django website and use git to manage the source code. Your website has various instances (one for each developer, at least).

When you perform a change on the model in a commit, everybody needs to update its own database. In some cases it is enough to run `python manage.py migrate`, in some other cases you need to run a few custom SQL queries and/or run some Python code to update values at various places.

How to automate this? Is there a clean way to bundle these "model updates" (for instance small shell scripts that do the appropriate actions) in the associated commits? I have thought about using git hooks for that, but as the code to be run changes over time, it is not clear to me how to use them for that purpose.

Comment: I don't think is a good idea track `/migrations` folder, I think every developer should keep it locally. So if you don't track migrations, when there is a change in `models` you should run `python manage makemigrations` and `python manage migrate`.

Comment: @Gocht no, no, no. Migrations are part of your code base and must be kept in source control.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is absolutely correct on this matter. Every developer keeping a local copy of migrations is the perfect recipe for **disaster**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*All* changes to models should be in migrations. If you "need to run a few custom SQL queries and/or run some Python code to update values" then those are migrations too, and should be written in a migration file.

Answer (score 1):

If you track `/migrations`, you can create/modify migration files as explained in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#writing-your-own)

This way, coworkers would just have to run `migrate` to execute the query

Answer (score 1):

You should track migrations. The only thing that you must keep an eye out for is at branch merge. If everyone uses a feature branch and develops on his branch then the changes are applied once the branch is integrated. At that point (pull request time or integration time) you need to make sure that the migrations make sense and if not fix them.

Answer (score 0):

You should see any database refactoring tools like [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) so you can source control your database changes. Here is a [wrapper](https://github.com/rhyolight/liquipy) for python.